# Is unconditional code considered a branch?

Tags: testing, unit-testing, complexity, test-coverage

Having simple code like this:

```
int A=5;
object X=Console.ReadLine()
if(Condition)
   DoSomething();
else
   DoStuff();
DoSomethingElse();
```

Some sources say there are actually 4 branches: First unconditional, two for the IF and another unconditional after the IF statement.
Some say there are only two branches.
What would be correct?
E.g. here:
http://www.ruleworks.co.uk/testguide/BS7925-2-Annex-B7.asp

Comment: The npath complexity of this code is 2.  Can you point to a source that claims four branches for this code?  The term 'branch' might be being misused or misunderstood.

Comment: Branch is just a block of code. Some sources consider only two branches in IF, but there is also a code before and after the IF. This is not npath complexity. The code consists of 4 pieces - block before the IF, two possible blocks for IF, and a block after the IF.

Comment: A branch is not a block of code - it is a specific point in the code that changes how the flow of the program executes.  The term 'branch' comes from [branch operations](http://www.johnloomis.org/microchip/pic32/assembly/mips2.html) in assembly.  These are if statements in higher level languages.

Comment: Ok I see, please check the link. They say there is 10 branches in the code sample there which is the point they make in distinction between branch and decision coverage. If there was 6 branches, it would be the same as decision coverage then.

Comment: It looks like the people who wrote the document you are referring to decided to invent their own meaning of branch which is very inconsistent with the common understanding. This is why names matter, A LOT. While it is common and expected to commandeer names in politics, it should really be taboo when it comes to science and the technical realms.

Comment: The document seems to distinguish between a basic block and a branch.  However, they mislabeled branches in the diagram - a branch is one of the nodes in the graph that has **two outbound arrows**. The arrows themselves are not branches, that's just program flow.

Comment: @Dunk: if you look at the link, you'll see that they didn't use non standard terms, it's just that their labeling Bx is being mistaken for BranchX instead of BasicblockX.  The OP's example (which is different from the links), has 4 blocks of code, 1 conditional branch and one unconditional.

Comment: @jmoreno "The branches are given by the arrows in the control flow graph; 10 in total." -- Branch is non-standard use there.  While... "The decisions are given by the basic blocks having more than one exit arrow, namely B2, B3 and B5.  Since each of these three blocks have two exits, we have six decisions to consider." -- Those decisions *are* the branches.  If one compiles the code, one will find three branch statements in the the assembly.  There is no such thing as an "unconditional branch" because a branch implies two or more different paths possible.  Unconditional implies only one path.

Comment: @MichaelT: 68k assembly has BRA (Branch Always), I assume other instruction sets have similar commands.  A branch is when the next instruction to be executed does not follow the current instruction, an unconditional branch is necessary with a if/else construct.  If the "DoSomething();" is a function call, that would be yet ANOTHER branching statement.

Comment: @jmoreno similar to the `J` vs `B` in MIPS - from the [68k instruction set](http://courses.ece.ubc.ca/259/Summary%2068000%20Instruction%20Set.pdf): "You use a BRA instruction to write position independent code, because the destination address (branch target address) is specified with respect to the current value of the PC. A JMP instruction does not produce position independent code."  Thus, the `BRA` follows the conventions of the other branch statements.

Comment: @MichaelT: yeah, it depends on context.  Branch statement vs branch of of code.  The example is clearly using branch statements, although they have it wrong, it should be 9 not 10 (probably implemented as 10, but logically 9).  My point being that the OP is confused, but the example wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origins of the word 'branch' in code comes from assembly.  An example of this can be seen in [MIPS assembly](http://www.johnloomis.org/microchip/pic32/assembly/mips2.html).  A branch is a conditional statement.

Before anyone jumps on me for point out that MIPS has a `b` instruction which has the description of "branch unconditionally" the key to the difference between `b` (branch unconditionally) and `j` (jump) is that the branch statements work off of relative addresses and the jump statements work off of absolute addresses.

There is also some terminology of unconditional branch in the realm of branch prediction.  A CPU with a pipeline will try to guess which way a branch statement goes and where it will end up after the branch.  It is possible to analize the assembly to see that a given branch will always execute given a certain set of conditions at the start of the pipline.  For example, the branch is based on if register 1 is greater than 0 or not.  If register 1 is 0, and no instructions in the pipeline change that, it is in essence an unconditional branch which can be executed safely (and not having to worry about flush the pipeline after [speculative execution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution) or stall until the branch can be decided).

All of the above was for very low level code.  In higher level code (as demonstrated in the question) the terminology of a branch is where code may follow two (or more in the case of a switch (pun not intended)) different paths.  From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_%28computer_science%29)

> A branch is sequence of code in a computer program which is conditionally executed depending on how the flow of control is altered at the branching point.

Unconditional code is not conditionally executed and thus is not a branch.

Comment: From your answer I feel like you are calling branches the decision nodes, while the branch is actually the path (each of them). Maybe my misunderstanding in English. However the main question is, how many branches does my example have?

Comment: @user970696 2 branches and the npath complexity is 2.  In the context of unit tests, for complete branch coverage you need 2 tests.  Calling `DoSomething();` is one branch and calling `DoStuff();` is another branch.

Answer (score 5):

I think branch here is meant to represent a block of code with a single linear path (no jumps starts or ends in the block) better known as a [basic block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block).

This concept is handy for compilers and other analysis tools to decide how a piece of code might behave (in the absence of exceptions) as each basic block is then an atomic operation in terms of the code around it.

For example, optimising compilers can look at each such block and decide how the dependencies for each individual instruction lies and possibly reorder them to make more efficient use of registers and the stack. Or, when only one exit path exists to a another block with only one entry, you can concatenate the blocks and eliminate the jump.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your context. For some analysis, such as what compilers do - you have 4 branches, since the post-if block can vary its behavior depending on which path the if goes (and if either conditional branch returns early). For some analysis like you might see in code coverage will vary to perhaps consider that somewhere between 2 and 4 branches depending on what is being done and if priority is given to the *choice* or to the *path*.

Neither view is particularly "correct" or not. They're human inventions to try and gain information and insight. Whichever metric does that better for the problem at hand is the "correct" one.